# Connection String in a .Net Windows Program

Tags: asp.net, connection-string

I'm working on my first Windows .Net application (as opposed to a .net web app, which I've done a lot of), and I have a question about database connection strings - is there an equivalent to the  section in web.config?

I want to be able to have the program run against our test database (which will required a different connection string.  What is the "canonical" way to define connection string objects in a Windows .Net application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than write this all down again, here's a good article on this subject:

[Storing and Retrieving Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Add an "application configuration" file to your project.  It will add a file called "app.config"  Put your connection in there.

When the app is compiled it will change the name of the config file to match your executable.  For example: MyApp.config.

I'm not sure what you mean by "canonical" way to define connection string objects.  Name them whatever you want.  Sometimes we use the name of the database, sometimes just the name of the project.

With regards to having multiple config files, we use Config Transforms.  Which name them app.config, app.debug.config, app.release.config, etc. and use configuration manager to define which one to use based on where it's being deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Non ASP.Net apps simply use app.config instead of web.config.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx).

> Connection strings can be stored as key/value pairs in the
>   connectionStrings section of the configuration element of an
>   application configuration file.